# Rejected call connects in the Voximplant callback application

Tags: voximplant

I'm implementing a callback and have a problem. I'm calling the user1, they answer the call, listen to the message, then I call the user2, and they reject the call. I have checks for call fails but this continue happens, what could be the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only reason for this can be if your user2 has voicemail which successfully answers the call, so your checs do not work. You can use voicemail detection to avoid this: https://voximplant.com/docs/guides/ai/voicemail